# Picking out a set of columns from a file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with many columns and I'm trying to pick out a subset of them. This subset is not defined by a continuous range (I can't iterate over 2 to 10, for instance).

Example:

```
$ cat test
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20

$ cat index
3
5
9
```

Expected output in this example:

```
3 5 9
6 10 18
```

I want the 3rd, 5th and 9th column (say).
I know I can do `awk '{print $3, $5, $9}' test` here but that is not feasible in my real data with > 100 columns and my needing to pick > 50 out of them. So please don't suggest manually writing all the column numbers.

One very bad solution that I have currently is as follows:

```
while read column
do
    awk -v var=$column '{print $var}' test > "$column"
done < index
```

This gets out the individual columns corresponding to the ones I want (saved in the file called `index`) into individual files (named according to the index) and then I paste them together.

This feels horribly inefficient and I'm sure there are better ways.
Could you suggest some?

Comment: what should be the final result, a new file containing picked subset of columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Simple [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) constructor for [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

As this question is tagged: [[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)], I would purpose a solution using both:

```
printf -v var "$%s, " $(<index)
awk "{print ${var%, }}" test

3 5 9
6 10 18
```

By using double-quotes  (`"`), I ensure that [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) won't see `$var` but only it's content.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input is space separated, you can use [`cut`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#cut-invocation) and [`paste`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#paste-invocation):

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f $(paste -s -d ',' index) infile
3 5 9
6 10 18
```

`cut` takes a comma separated list of fields in its `-f` option, and `paste -s -d ','` creates that list from the `index` file.

It your input is tab separated, you can drop `-d ' '` from the `cut` command.

Comment: Wow, that is ridiculously neat. I was able to get rid of two small loops from my program and put in that one liner. Upvoted. I'll wait for some more answers before accepting one.

Answer (score 1):

In comparison with other good answers, mine seems to be verbose.
 But I can leave it here as an alternative for some complex/sophisticated cases(*delimiting* rules or fields filtering):

Let's say `test` file contains:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 15 25 30 35 45 75 80 90
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 40 50 60 70 85 100
```

We need to extract all fields with positions specified in the file `index` with contents:

```
3
5
9
8
12
14
```

The job:

```
indices=$(<index)
echo $indices | awk -v f="$indices" 'BEGIN{split(f, a, "\n")}
     {f=""; for (i=1;i in a;i++) {printf "%s%s", f, $a[i]; f=OFS} print ""}' test
```

you can set/adjust custom delimiter within `split(f, a, "\n")` function call

The output:

```
3 5 9 8 25 35
6 10 18 16 50 70
```

Comment: file `index` contain `$'3\n5\n9'`, not `'3,5,9'`

Comment: @F.Hauri, ok, fixed. It was just another case with another delimiter

Comment: Tested with bigger files: `for ((i=1;i<100;i++));do for ((l=i;l<=100*i;l+=i));do echo -n $l\ ;done;echo;done >test` : You're script take `10ms` where mine do the jobs in ~`2ms`.

Comment: @F.Hauri, congratulations, what else? There could be more complex tasks, for ex. *to print only odd or even column numbers from index file* - how does your solution solve such task?

Comment: Another task may require another algorithm... You're solution could match another case, but there, it's clearly not the quickest way.

Comment: I like uniform and scalable solutions which can cover many cases. Do you want to have your "speedy" answer accepted as the best one? I don't mind. Let the OP decide

Comment: And for answering your question: odd entries in `index` file: `printf -v var "$%s, " $(sed <index  'N;s/.*\n//p;d')` and even: `printf -v var "$%s, " $(sed <index  'p;N;d')`. This stay very quick.

Answer (score 0):

Awk only:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR { a[$1]; next }                     # code for index file
{                                           # code for test file below this point
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        printf "%s%s", (i in a ? $i OFS : ""), (i==NF ? ORS : "")
}' index test
3 5 9 
6 10 18
```

Solution reads in the `index` file and stores field numbers to be printed to `a` hash. Then all the fields of `test` are iterated thru with `for` and fields `i` in `a` are `printf`ed out finishing with `ORS`.

Comment: Do you want to add some lines of explanation for others reading this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Since I got a lot of answers I thought I would benchmark them.
I generated a file with a 1000 columns and 10,000 lines. To generate the index, I randomly chose a subset containing 100 numbers.

@Benjamin W-

```
time cut -d ' ' -f $(paste -s -d ',' index) test | wc -l
10000

real    0m0.844s
user    0m0.839s
sys     0m0.020s
```

@F. Hauri

```
printf -v var "$%s, " $(<index) ; time awk "{print ${var%, }}" test
10000

real    0m0.242s
user    0m0.233s
sys     0m0.017s
```

@RomanPerekhrest

```
indices=$(<index)
time echo $indices | awk -v f="$indices" 'BEGIN{split(f, a, "\n")}
     {f=""; for (i=1;i in a;i++) {printf "%s%s", f, $a[i]; f=OFS} print ""}' test

10000

real    0m0.460s
user    0m0.456s
sys     0m0.016s
```

@James Brown

```
time awk '
NR==FNR { a[$1]; next }
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
        printf "%s%s", (i in a ? $i OFS : ""), (i==NF ? ORS : "")
}' index test | wc -l

10000

real    0m2.667s
user    0m2.658s
sys     0m0.018s
```

Comment: the timing on second solution is not fair.  It leaves the first part out.

Comment: @karakfa, I tested that part independently before posting the answer. That adds only 0.001 s to the real time and hence I ignored it. Similarly, for the third answer, the definition of the variable "indices" is not taken into the time calculation because when tested independently, it was negligible as compared to the main part of the answer.